# Angular Strap tab does not update tab content until browser resize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am using the following code to use tabs within a modal.

```
<div bs-tabs>
    <div ng-repeat="tabs in Filters" title="{{ tabs.title }}" name="{{ tabs.title }}" bs-pane>
        <label class="tag-checkboxes col-sm-6" ng-repeat="tag in tabs.filters | orderBy: 'name'">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.checked" ng-change="ModifyFilter(tag)"> {{tag.name}}
            </input>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which pulls it's data from a JSON source structured like this:

```
{
    "title": "Difficulty",
    "icon": "difficulty-icon",
    "filters": [{
        "name": "Easy",
        "checked": false
    }]
},
{
    "title": "Equipment",
    "icon": "equipment-icon",
    "filters": [{
        "name": "Rope",
        "checked": false
    }
    }]
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome 47, however in Chrome 38 (annoying the specific browser I have to target due to a closed network) the content of the tab (all the checkboxes) does not show until the browser is resized or I open the inspector, basically anything that changes the dom slightly I guess.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this issue also causes an issue with inputs within modals. The following css fixes this.

The `position: fixed;` seems to break things.

```
.modal.center .modal-dialog{
    position:absolute !important;
    top:40%;left:50%;
    min-width:320px;
    max-width:630px;
    width:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)
}
```